# How to distance from json?

Tags: php, json

Hy i try make distance from more than 100 points. I use function distance in php to make distance but i don't know to make distance from json This my code **PHP**

```
<?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

$r = distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo $r;
?>
```

I have **JSON** example like this

```
[{"latitude":"-7.285833","longitude":"112.725947"},
{"latitude":"-7.302902","longitude":"112.684648"},
{"latitude":"-7.332048","longitude":"112.669293"},
{"latitude":"-7.364344","longitude":"112.685177"},
{"latitude":"-7.384560","longitude":"112.717475"},
{"latitude":"-7.398474","longitude":"112.773600"},
{"latitude":"-7.417114","longitude":"112.729653"},
{"latitude":"-7.429452","longitude":"112.797426"},
{"latitude":"-7.444224","longitude":"112.787337"},
{"latitude":"-7.494794","longitude":"112.779152"}]
```

I don't know how to make distance from json data, please help me to solve my problem, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should add a little more detail.

Is your intention to parse JSON with PHP and use the objects as input into your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to decode your json first:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('[{"latitude":"-7.285833","longitude":"112.725947"},
{"latitude":"-7.302902","longitude":"112.684648"},
{"latitude":"-7.332048","longitude":"112.669293"},
{"latitude":"-7.364344","longitude":"112.685177"},
{"latitude":"-7.384560","longitude":"112.717475"},
{"latitude":"-7.398474","longitude":"112.773600"},
{"latitude":"-7.417114","longitude":"112.729653"},
{"latitude":"-7.429452","longitude":"112.797426"},
{"latitude":"-7.444224","longitude":"112.787337"},
{"latitude":"-7.494794","longitude":"112.779152"}]', true);

$r = distance($data[0]['latitude'], $data[0]['longitude'], $data[1]['latitude'], $data[1]['longitude'], "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo $r;
?>
```

Will use your method on the first 2 lat longs.

Comment: if i have JSON data more than 100 if efisien use this method

Comment: @Rizka not sure I understand your question but yes you can use this method to 100 (or more/less) values. Look at `for`, `foreach` or `while`

Comment: @RizkaNugroho, I'm not sure where your data comes from or how you want to use it but as Andreas said, you can loop through your data. Your data size limitations will be with your php configuration but 100 should not be a problem

Comment: @CUGreen actually now that I look at your code you are missing the `true` in the Jason decode to make it an array

Answer (score 0):

I can't compete with CUGreens answer since there isn't much other ways to decode json.
But I think there is some improvements that can be made in your code.
Your code always outputs "x kilometers".

What I did was to use the return to send back the unit to the main function as an array.
This will also keep number and text separated so you can for example round the number and still output the text.

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return array($miles * 1.609344, " kilometers");
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return array($miles * 0.8684, " nautical miles");
    } else {
        return array($miles, " miles");
    }
}

$r = distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K"); 
echo $r[0] . $r[1];
```

https://3v4l.org/vnRFv